# Presenting 2 select statements with Group By clause

Tags: mysql

I want to join two or more select statements that have a group by clause, but it isn't working.

```
SELECT COUNT(`rank`) AS rank1,sitename
FROM `larrdb_ranking` 
INNER JOIN larrdb_site_list USING (sid)
WHERE rank=1
GROUP BY sitename
UNION 
SELECT COUNT(`rank`) AS rank2 ,sitename
FROM `larrdb_ranking` 
INNER JOIN larrdb_site_list USING (sid)
WHERE rank=2
GROUP BY sitename
```

All what I get is the first statement working, but the second statement doesn't.. I don't get the rank2 selected

**UPDATE:**

Union All doesn't work too:

```
    SELECT COUNT(`rank`) AS rank1,sitename
FROM `larrydb_ranking` 
INNER JOIN larrydb_site_list USING (sid)
WHERE rank=1
GROUP BY sitename
UNION ALL
SELECT COUNT(`rank`) AS rank2 ,sitename
FROM `larrydb_ranking` 
INNER JOIN larrydb_site_list USING (sid)
WHERE rank=2
GROUP BY sitename
```

column..rank2 isn't being presented

Comment: Can you specify that in which format you want your output and also specify your table structure with data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT SUM(IF(rank=1, 1, 0)) AS rank1, SUM(IF(rank=2, 1, 0)) AS rank2,sitename
FROM `larrydb_ranking` 
INNER JOIN larrydb_site_list USING (sid)
GROUP BY sitename
```